# Sort array/vector of string

Tags: c++, string, sorting

How can i sort array/vector by repetition of elements?
For example

Input

```
Leo
Mike
Eric
Leo
Leo
```

Output    **_ *_***  _    Or

```
Leo       Leo
Leo       Eric
Leo       Mike
Eric
Mike
```

Comment: And which language do you use?

Comment: Try `std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());`

Comment: @user - Then write your own sort function.

Comment: @Ramhound:  Why reinvent this wheel?

Comment: I am confused:  what is your sorting criteria?  What does "by repetition of elements" mean?

Comment: @James: I think he means for the most common element to appear first in the list, etc.

Comment: This makes a little more sense now.

Comment: Too bad you can't use SQL: `select name group by name order by count(*) desc`

Comment: @John - If user is not happy with ABC sorting then applying a custom sort algorithim is the solution.  Based on the fact the user wants something that is not standard.  The user seems to be over his head is all.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend processing your data in 3 passes:

1. Use std::sort to get all repeated elements adjacent to each other.
2. Iterate over your sorted range recording the length and position of each equal_range.
3. Now you can resort your sequence based on the data you've recovered in step 2.  You may consider using stable_search in this phase if you could like a secondary search key to be alphabetical.

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to explain this in words and have you write the code, but I'm finding that I'm so familiar with C++ now, that it's a lot easier for me to just write code.  Slight variation on what Steve said.  Your original vector of strings is v.

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;
for(auto i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i)
    m[*i]++;

typedef std::pair<std::string, int> P;
auto comp_by_second = [](const P & lhs, const P & rhs) { return lhs.second < rhs.second; };

for(auto i=v.begin(); !m.empty(); )
{
    auto j = std::max_element(m.begin(), m.end(), comp_by_second);
    while(j->second-- > 0)
        *i++ = j->first;
    m.erase(j);
}
```

Comment: *Pedantry Mode On*: Your `P` typedef is wrong; the value type of a `map<K, V>` is `pair<K const, V>`. One technical fix would be to change it to `typedef std::pair<std::string const, int> P;`, but the preferred route is to use the `map`'s `value_type`: `typedef std::map<std::string, int>::value_type P;`, or better yet its `const_reference`: `typedef std::map<std::string, int>::const_reference P; auto comp_by_second = [](P lhs, P rhs) { ... };`

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do this. A relatively simple way is to build a `map<string, size_t>` containing the counts of each element (just iterate over your input vector, incrementing the count for each string you see). Then write all the keys in the map to a vector, and `std::sort` that vector with a comparator that compares the number from the map.

That involves more map lookups than strictly necessary, so you could instead write a vector of *pairs* from the map, then sort the pairs, and finally create your vector of strings from the sorted pairs.